# clearcase: shared dynamic views in windows

Tags: windows, version-control, clearcase, net-use

Clearcase in unix allows 'export views', which non-clearcase users can mount via nfs.

Can a similar feat be achieved with the windows version? I want to use windows filesharing on a dynamic view, so that the MVFS will be mounted on one system, and all other computers could simply use windows filesharing to mount it (readonly if that matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the help page "[Configuring non-ClearCase access on Linux or the UNIX system](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/non-cc-access.htm)" clearly states:

> Non-ClearCase access is not supported on hosts running Linux or the UNIX system and Rational ClearCase LT, or on any Rational ClearCase Windows host.

I would rather try and use a snapshot view on Windows, which you can then share (regular windows folder share) on your disk in order for others to access.